# I am getting the make error for the AMR Source Code

Tags: cygwin, cpu-architecture

I have downloaded the AMR source code from the 3GPP website.
When i am trying to compile it with out any modifications, i am getting the error
can't determine architecture; adapt typedefs.h to your platform

```
D:\AMR_3Gpp\26073-800\c-code> make
rm -f *.o core
rm -f *.a encoder decoder
gcc -c -Wall -pedantic-errors -I. -O3 -DWMOPS=0 -DVAD1 agc.c
In file included from typedef.h:50,
                 from agc.h:24,
                 from agc.c:20:
typedefs.h:179:2: error: #error "can't determine architecture; adapt typedefs.h to your platform"
In file included from agc.c:31:
basic_op.h:33: warning: conflicting types for built-in function `round'
make: *** [agc.o] Error 1
D:\AMR_3Gpp\26073-800\c-code>
```

I am using the cygwin on windows machine. So if anyone knows or faced this error "can't determine architecture; adapt typedefs.h to your platform". Please help me in resolving it.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

---

```
/*
 ********* Check current platform
 */
#if defined(__MSDOS__)
#define PC
#define PLATFORM "PC"
#define LSBFIRST
#elif defined(__osf__)
#define OSF
#define PLATFORM "OSF"
#define LSBFIRST
#elif defined(__sun__) || defined(__sun)
#define SUN
#define PLATFORM "SUN"
#undef LSBFIRST
#elif defined(linux) && defined(i386)
#define PC
#define PLATFORM "PC"
#define LSBFIRST
#else
#error "can't determine architecture; adapt typedefs.h to your platform"
#endif
```

Comment: Look for this text in typedefs.h and post the surrounding macros here

Comment: Hi James, as the text in comments cannot be formatted much, i have pasted above.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this project was never ported to CYGWIN's gcc environment.

Either

1. Find out from the project how (or if) they support any Windows C compiler and use it. According to their site, it looks like they support MinGW -- http://www.mingw.org/
2. Port to CYGWIN GCC yourself -- to start: "adapt typedefs.h to your platform"

Comment: Hi Lou Franco, I am a new bie to linux. Will you please guide me in how to port with some links. So that i can start with.

Comment: You'd be better off to just build with MINGW because there may be more dependencies on it that just this, but if you want to try  (1) find out the what GCC defines to identify itself http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html (2) add a section `#elif defined(__GNUC__)` (3) define the macros that the other platforms do (copy from MSDOS to start) -- (4) test and find out if you need to do more